# associations.build works, build_association does not

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What could be causing this to work:

```
@document.template_variables.build(name: var.name, tag: var.tag)
```

but this not to?

```
@document.build_template_variable(name: var.name, tag: var.tag)
```

BTW, the top one doesn't seem to store those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@document.template_variables.build(name: var.name, tag: var.tag)` is for **one-to-many** relation,

`@document.build_template_variable(name: var.name, tag: var.tag)` is for **one-to-one** relation.

Depends on in your `Document` model, it's `has_many :template_variable` or `has_one :template_variable`, you should choose one way to build the association.

Comment: Ah, right. Yeah, it is **one-to-many**. That wouldn't explain why it won't save those arguments though.

Comment: @emm What do you mean by `save those arguments`? save to the database?

Comment: Yeah. Records created with that method have `nil names` and `tags`.